What is the correct way to implement the sectioned LazyColumn with cards?
What is the correct way to implement the following UI with Jetpack Compose?
Note: it is continuous scroll, no nested scrolling

At first it looks something like following
- LazyColumn
---- Card 1
-------- LazyColumn
------------ a1
------------ a2
------------ a3
------------ .
------------ .
------------ an
---- Card 2
-------- LazyColumn
------------ b1
------------ b2
------------ .
------------ .
------------ bm

and so on...

but I believe the above approach is not performance efficient as it has nested LazyColumns... Another approach would be something like by flattening the items...
- LazyColumn
---- Card 1 Header
---- a1
---- a2
---- .
---- .
---- an
---- Card 1 Footer
---- spacer

and so on...

card header & footer would be like the shapes with rounded corners at either top or bottom


Now, if I go with the 2nd approach, it'll be hard to get the shadows and other effects right. I tried elevating the individual items with shadow... but that doesn't look good as it clearly separates them from each other...

Here is my code for the bottom of fake card
@Composable
fun FakeCardBottom(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 16.dp, bottomEnd = 16.dp)

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(4.dp, shape)
            .clip(shape)
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(16.dp)
    )
}

how do I get rid of the &in-between& shadows? or is there any better solution for this?

Can you explain what performance problems you experience with the nested LazyColumn approach? Also, your second approach will behave differently from the first one because you won't have a nested scroll behavior. I think that should be the deciding factor: Can you clarify what you would prefer?
